# Is there a modifiable Iterable type?

Tags: dart, generics, iterable

I need a modifiable collection like a `List` or a `Set` to be passed as a parameter. Using `Iterable` doesn't guarantee this argument to have methods like `add` or `remove`.

Example method:

```dart
void foo(Iterable bar) {
    bar.add(); // The method 'add' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable'.
}
```

Is there a class / interface for (modifiable) collections which guarantees those methods? If not, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is *not* a modifiable type. Very early (before Dart 1) we had some other types in our hierarchy, but we decided to avoid including them because things were getting a bit too complex.

I still wish we'd shipped a `List` interface without the mutation members.